# vim syntax keyword only highlight unbound occurrences

Tags: python, vim, syntax, syntax-highlighting

I have a syntax file with the following definitions:

```
syn keyword pythonBuiltinFunc           __import__ abs all any
                                        \ bin bool bytearray
                                        \ callable chr classmethod compile complex
                                        \ delattr dict dir divmod
                                        \ enumerate eval
                                        \ filter float format frozenset
                                        \ getattr globals hasattr hash hex
                                        \ id input int isinstance issubclass iter
                                        \ len list locals
                                        \ map max min next
                                        \ object oct open ord pow property
                                        \ range repr reversed round
                                        \ set setattr slice sorted
                                        \ staticmethod str sum super
                                        \ tuple type vars zip
                                        \ nextgroup=pythonArgs skipwhite
```

The problem is that this matches occurrences of `next` (e.g.) even when that name is referenced as an object's attribute, as in `obj.next`, and this messes up the highlighting.

While I might buy that it's useful to not shadow built-in names, I'm not sure that I buy this for bounded names.

Does any one have thoughts on how to apply the above definitions, but exclude the pathological case I mentioned below? I guess I'd be allowing whitespace in the word pattern, but ignoring it in the match?

Answer (score 0):

In order to exclude those builtins in object attributes using Vim's syntax containment rules, you'd have to define a pattern to detect objects; I guess that's not possible.

That leaves you with converting those keywords to `:syntax match` and adding *lookbehind assertion* to it to avoid matching as part of `obj.builtin`, like this:

```
:syntax match pythonBuildinFunc "\.\@<!\<next\>"
```